# Detecting Images Within Invisible iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I wish to reference this `iframe`:

```
<iframe id= "bro" src="http://www.youtube.com" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>
```

Instead of `getBackgroundPage()` in the following code:

> img.src = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().imageSrc[0];

I've tried:

> img.src = document.getByElementId("bro").imageSrc[0];

That failed hard. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
document.getByElementId("bro")
```

will return an iframe object, and it doesn't have property called `imageSrc`.

With that, assuming you have the iframe object, you will then have to deal with [Cross Domain Policy](http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls) that will prevent you from accessing the content of the iframe.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your answer at all. How does it not contain imageSrc?

Comment: also you suggested i use an invisible iframe.

Comment: In your case, iFrame should work. Please read the page that I linked on how to get around the cross domain policy.